# Массив в конструкторе С++

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, visual-c++

Недавно познакомился с классами, но при попытке передать массив в конструктор программа программа создает объект заполненный нулями(насколько я понимаю).

```
class interpritation {
public:
    int params[4]{};
    interpritation(int(&params)[4]) { copy(params, params + 4, params); }

    void show() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            cout << params[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    int first[4]{ 0,0,1,1 };
    interpritation f(first);
    f.show();  
}
```

Вместо ожидаемого вывода `0 0 1 1` программа выводит `0 0 0 0`. Как правильно передавать массив в конструктор?

Comment: Ну вы бы хоть дали разные имена параметру и члену...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема в том, что при выполнении кода конструктора

```
copy(params, params + 4, params);
```

`params` ссылается исключительно на аргумент конструктора. Т.е. вы копируете массив в самого себя. Член класса при этом не изменяется вовсе. Для разрешения ситуации можно либо дать различные имена члену-данных и аргументу конструтора, либо там, где требуется член, использовать `this`, например:

```
copy(params, params + 4, this->params);
```

В данной ситуации ещё хорошим подспорьем могла бы выступить константность. Т.к. входной массив не планируется изменять, аргумент конструктора логично было объявить как `const int(&params)[4]`. В этом случае запись

```
copy(params, params + 4, params);
```

просто не скомпилировалась бы, что позволило бы скорее понять в чём причина.

Answer (score 2):

```
interpritation(int(&par)[4]) { copy(par, par + 4, params); }
```

спасет отца русской демократии... (с) О. Бендер

Comment: Великий комбинатор прав